# -[__NSCFDictionary Title]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have created an application that populates a table from JSON data I pull from my local host. I am able to search through this data using a search bar and have added a button to add the rows to another table which I am using a library for a users favourite objects. So now that Ive this all working I'm trying to create a detail view that when a user clicks on a row in the table they are brought to a new view controller and then they can view the full details of the object as the rows in the initial table only have the title and author listed in each row.

I have made the Segue and created the view controller ect and when I try to populate a few `UILabel`s on the `detaiViewController` I get a error:

Comment: My guess? `[_papers objectAtIndex:self.listTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row]` is a `NSDictionary` object, not a `Paper` object.

Comment: And there's a very good hint: -[__NSCFDictionary Title]: unrecognized selector which is what you get if you try to send a Title: message to an NSDictionary :-)

Comment: Why are you using the `weak` attribute, do you understand what it does ?

Comment: You need to show how is parsed your JSON, how is populated `_papers`.

Comment: @Larme I've edited the question and I'm not too sure why I used weak i just followed a tutorial

Comment: Ok. You should use `locations` and not `_papers` for your UITableView. In other words, `_papers` is array with the JSON, and `locations` is the array of PARSED JSON. So `Paper *myPaper = [locations objectAtIndex:self.listTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];` should work, but I recommend to use location elsewhere in the datasource/delegate method for `self.listTableView`.

Comment: okay thank you, that has stopped it crashing and the segue performs however the text fields are blank ? Any ideas .@Larme

Comment: Never mind Got it working now .. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
self.Title.text = self.paper.Title;
```

to:

```
self.Title.text = self.paper[@"Title"];
```

Use awakeFromNib instead of viewDidLoad

Comment: This definitely seems like the right idea. When i typed this in it straight away won't build saying "Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object type Paper"

Comment: Any chance you can give a snippet of your Paper class?

Comment: that should be some extra info up now I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe papers dictionary store others NSDictionary, not Paper object. When you parse a JSON, it will parse to iOS SDK class, such as [] parse to NSArray, "" parse to NSString, {} parse to NSDictionary.

So, I guess your JSON will parse to an array of dictionary. It cannot return a Paper for you. You have to assign values in each dictionary to one your Paper, and put it in a NSArray of Paper.

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

_papers = [json objectForKey:@"Papers"];

You are populating the locations array from retrieving elements from _papers. Actually _papers holds list of NSDictionaries and when in prepareForsegue you just get an element from _papers which is a dictionary so thats why it is giving error. You have to store this locations array and retrieve elements from it because you are parsing the json into paper in the loop and putting it in locations hope it helps.